# How to perform a syntax check in Ansible Tower?

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

Via command line, there is the :

```
ansible-playbook --syntax-check
```

command, is there a way to check the syntax of a Playbook in a job template from Tower ?

Answer (score 1):

You can dry run the your job using the `check` option.
[image]